# HTML5 Form fields moving on mouse click

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-11

I've got an IE11 specific problem that's driving me insane. Here's an image of the form:

[image: Form fields properly aligned]

Functionally it's fine but in IE11 I'm encountering a problem when users click on form fields in the right hand column. It moves input fields in the left column below it to the right:

[image: Form fields misaligned from mouse click]

Added to this, if someone types information into a field on the left hand side, they can then click or tab into the right hand column and it displays fine:

[image: Form fields aligned properly on mouse click]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-border">
  <h2>Billing Address:</h2>
  <input id="search" name="search" placeholder="Start typing a postcode or address" type="text" value />
  <div class="left container-half">  
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name(s)" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="right container-half">
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="left container-half">
    <input id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="right container-half">
    <input id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="left container-half">
    <input id="city" name="town" placeholder="City" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="right container-half">
    <input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" type="text" value />
  </div>
  <div class="left container-half">
    <select class="country" id="country" name="country">
      <option value="">Country</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.container-half {
  width: 50%;
}

.container-half input[type="text"] {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-half select {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  .container-half {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }

  .container-half input[type="text"],
  .container-half select {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}

input[type="text"] {
  float: inherit;
  background-color : rgb(76, 171, 148); 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: white;
}

select {
    padding: 12px;
    float: inherit;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(76,171,148);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border:none;
    width: 45%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; 
    box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas about what's causing IE11 to behave this way? Appearance is fine in FF and Chrome.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You could always merge those media queries in the end of the css file so it would be one big media query. Anyway, another problem is your `box-sizing` which should be `border-box` . It won't fix your problems, but it will surely help your layouts.

Comment: Please ignore what I wrote pre-edit. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem I failed to notice my input had been preserved through refresh. I definitely do need to clean the CSS up. I'll do that now.

Comment: Works perfectly for me in ie11 - here's a fiddle of it for quicker checking http://jsfiddle.net/39sq3ov1/

Comment: Yeah, that is weird, I'm rebuilding the site slowly in jsFiddle to see what other features it could be. After you posted that I thought it might be related to a modal box I've got for the refund policy but that also works fine in fiddle and IE11. I'll try commenting out the postcode anywhere stuff instead.

Comment: Ok, it's not the postcode anywhere code. Commenting that out still gives me the same behaviour in IE11 on the development version of the site but it's fine on the fiddle. This is definitely confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your second screenshot (the "moved" one), you can see, that the "Address 1" field is slightly smaller than the other fields. It seems, IE has a problem with width in percent and margin in px.
Because you float all your elements, I would suggest to clear after every double line and add an empty field element for the right "just in case" in the last row:

```
CSS:
.clearence
    {
        clear: both;
    }

HTML:
<div class = "container-border">
    <h2>Billing Address:</h2>
    <input id = "search" name = "search" placeholder = "Start typing a postcode or address" type = "text" value />
    <div class = "left container-half">
        <input id = "firstname" name = "firstname" placeholder = "First name(s)" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "right container-half">
        <input id = "lastname" name = "lastname" placeholder = "Last name" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "clearence"></div>
    <div class = "left container-half">
        <input id = "address1" name = "address1" placeholder = "Address 1" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "right container-half">
        <input id = "address2" name = "address2" placeholder = "Address 2" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "clearence"></div>
    <div class = "left container-half">
        <input id = "city" name = "town" placeholder = "City" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "right container-half">
        <input id = "postcode" name = "postcode" placeholder = "Postcode" type = "text" value />
    </div>
    <div class = "clearence"></div>
    <div class = "left container-half">
        <select class = "country" id = "country" name = "country">
            <option value = "">Country</option>
            <option selected = "selected" value = "GB">United Kingdom</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class = "right container-half">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class = "clearence"></div>
</div>
```

And I think you can remove the "value" from the text fields, It's not needed if you don't put ... well, values in the fields.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have fixed the problem nicely!